# del class with wxpython inside conditional works unexpectedly

Tags: python, wxpython, conditional-statements, del

I am trying to delete an instance of a class when a condition is done.
But I am having issues, because it´s being deleted before it enters the condition.
I don´t know what´s happening...
The code uses wxpython with some buttons for deleting ítems, so I build the buttons correctly on init but when I try to delete an ítem, before it reaches the first conditional, it seems to be deleted by the las conditional, that should be never done before.
So I don´t know where the problem comes from...
The error I get when i press the button 'deleteitem' for the first time is:

'local variable 'T' referenced before assignment' (in 6th the line:... if T.items>0:)

But if I delete the last line del(T) it doesn´t give any error.

Here goes the basic code:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=8

T=Test()



if button.GetName()=='deleteitem': 
    if T.items>0:
        T.items-=1
        if T.items<0:
            del(T)
```

EDITED:

OK, as the example I posted firstly can work, here goes the code that doesn´t work:

```
import wx

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=8

T=Test()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title,
                          pos=(150, 150), size=(350, 200))

        self.btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Press to delete Item, current Items: "+str(T.items))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton, self.btn)


    def OnButton(self, evt):
        print 'Current Items: '+str(T.items)
        self.btn.SetLabel('Press to delete Item, current Items: '+str(T.items))
        if T.items>0:
            T.items-=1
            if T.items==0:
                del(T)


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, "Simple wxPython App")
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

app = MyApp()
app.MainLoop()
```

**FINAL WORKING CODE:**

```
import wx

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=8

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        self.T=Test()
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title,
                          pos=(150, 150), size=(350, 200))

        self.btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Press to delete Item, current Items: "+str(self.T.items))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton, self.btn)


    def OnButton(self, evt):
        if self.T.items>0:
            self.T.items-=1
            if self.T.items==0:
                del(self.T)
                self.btn.SetLabel('Deleted instance T')
            else:
                self.btn.SetLabel('Press to delete Item, current Items: '+str(self.T.items))
                print 'current Items: '+str(self.T.items)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, "Simple wxPython App")
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

app = MyApp()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are leaving out some relevant code because this code:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=8

T=Test()



if True: 
    if T.items>0:
        T.items-=1
        if T.items<0:
            del(T)
```

executes without error.

In any case, it sounds like your code is some variation of [Variable scope in nested functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452942/variable-scope-in-nested-functions).

**Response to new code:**

As far as I can tell, `del` localizes a variable:

Example 1:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=8

T = Test()

class Dog(object):
    def dostuff(self):
        print 'executing dostuff()'
        if T.items > 10:  #This will never be True
            T

Dog().dostuff()

--output:--
executing dostuff()
```

Example 2:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=8

T = Test()

class Dog(object):
    def dostuff(self):
        print 'executing dostuff()'
        if T.items > 10:  #This will never be True
            del T


Dog().dostuff()

--output:--
executing dostuff()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 14, in <module>
    Dog().dostuff()
  File "1.py", line 10, in dostuff
    if T.items > 10:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'T' referenced before assignment
```

So it looks like the parser marks T as a local variable inside the dostuff() function--because you can only `del` local names (unless you declare T to be global inside dostuff() ).  As a result, python won't look outside the dostuff() function for the value of T.

Therefore, another solution(not recommended) would be to do this:

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items=8

T = Test()

class Dog(object):
    def dostuff(self):
        global T  #<===HERE
        print 'executing dostuff()'

        if T.items > 10:
            del T


Dog().dostuff()

--output:--
executing dostuff()
```

To solve your problem, I would add the following to the end of your `__init__()` function:

```
self.T = Test()
```

Or, you could pass T as an argument to `__init__()`.  It's generally considered terrible program design to have functions inside a class manipulating global variables.

Comment: Thanks 7stud, It seems the error is related in the link you post...But anyway, I have updated the code so that now it doesn´t work.

Comment: Thank you very much 7stud! 
It works perfect!

...I edited and posted the new working code,

Comment: @RubenMedrano, In your post, I read: *But if I delete the last line del(T) it doesn´t give any error.*, which negates everything I claimed was happening.  If you care to look, I changed my explanation.

Comment: 7stud, I see you have changed  it. Now it is more clear. Anyway, I should have post the full code as a first post. Thanks for your explanation and for your time! ........I should learn now how to pass an instance between classes, because I will need it for my program :)